# How do i send server id from adapter to Activity which operates fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have `CustomAdapter` which operates on SQLite database and creates and stores `server_name`, `time_stamp` id, etc. and I want it when I click it, it passes `server_id` to activity which operates 2 fragments and both of them need id to refer to to get other items from database.

From other post I learnt i should in `onBindViewHolder` create intent and put extras but I don't really know how to pass it to fragments.

Here is fragment from `ServerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Server server = serversList.get(position);
    holder.note.setText(server.getNote());
}
```

Here is the activity which operates fragments:

```
public class ParentItemListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parentitemlist);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

I've used your 1st code and attached it to onClick

```
start(MainActivity.this, position);
```

But I'm having problem understanding 2nd part
    public class ItemListOwnedFragment extends Fragment {

```
public ItemListOwnedFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);
 Log.d("ItemListOwnedFragment", "XD " + "here i want server name" );
    } 
}
```

Don't really understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass data for your hosting `Activity`, you could insert data inside your intent, e.g.

```
public static void start(Context context, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ID_KEY, id);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then when you get your data in `Activity` you could attach it to each of your fragments in the `Bundle`, e.g.

```
public static Fragment newInstance(long id) {
    SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(ID_KEY_FOR_FRAGMENT, id);
    clientsFragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

---

Other way how to share business logic across `Activity` and `Fragment` is to use [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) - you could share you ViewModel across different entities with one `context`. e.g. get `ViewModel` in `Fragment` by Activity's `Context`. But that should be done if your business logic really could be shared.

Comment: @wokstym check my example, in order to pass smth to fragment you need to put it into budle and then in fragment retrieve it via getArguments